# Anyone know why this UNION is giving me a certain Error, I see nothing wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've shown the Error first and then the SQL with the bit i'm adding in commented out, in this state it works fine. If I comment back in the UNION part i get the error. IT all works and PremiseMeteredPricings is identical to PremisePricings field wise etc and can easily do a normal UNION.

**THE ERROR:**
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
Invalid column name 'PremiseId'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Invalid column name 'PremiseId'.

**THE SQL**

```
select PremiseId,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Water' and WholesalePricing=0 then FixedCharge end) RetailWaterFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Water' and WholesalePricing=0 then VolumetricCharge end) RetailWaterVar,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Waste' and WholesalePricing=0 then FixedCharge end) RetailWasteFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Waste' and WholesalePricing=0 then VolumetricCharge end) RetailWasteVar,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Roads Drainage' and WholesalePricing=0 then FixedCharge end) RetailRoadsFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Roads Drainage' and WholesalePricing=0 then VolumetricCharge end) RetailRoadsVar,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Property Drainage' and WholesalePricing=0 then FixedCharge end) RetailPropertyFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Property Drainage' and WholesalePricing=0 then VolumetricCharge end) RetailPropertyVar,

  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Water' and WholesalePricing=1 then FixedCharge end) WholesaleWaterFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Water' and WholesalePricing=1 then VolumetricCharge end) WholesaleWaterVar,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Waste' and WholesalePricing=1 then FixedCharge end) WholesaleWasteFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Waste' and WholesalePricing=1 then VolumetricCharge end) WholesaleWasteVar,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Roads Drainage' and WholesalePricing=1 then FixedCharge end) WholesaleRoadsFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Roads Drainage' and WholesalePricing=1 then VolumetricCharge end) WholesaleRoadsVar,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Property Drainage' and WholesalePricing=1 then FixedCharge end) WholesalePropertyFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Property Drainage' and WholesalePricing=1 then VolumetricCharge end) WholesalePropertyVar

from PremisePricings 
where UserId = 'cdb370f7-b995-4d99-adc9-c00c7e837bb4'
group by PremiseId

UNION 

 select PremiseId,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Water' and WholesalePricing=0 then FixedCharge end) RetailWaterFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Water' and WholesalePricing=0 then VolumetricCharge end) RetailWaterVar,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Waste' and WholesalePricing=0 then FixedCharge end) RetailWasteFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Waste' and WholesalePricing=0 then VolumetricCharge end) RetailWasteVar,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Roads Drainage' and WholesalePricing=0 then FixedCharge end) RetailRoadsFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Roads Drainage' and WholesalePricing=0 then VolumetricCharge end) RetailRoadsVar,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Property Drainage' and WholesalePricing=0 then FixedCharge end) RetailPropertyFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Property Drainage' and WholesalePricing=0 then VolumetricCharge end) RetailPropertyVar,

  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Water' and WholesalePricing=1 then FixedCharge end) WholesaleWaterFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Water' and WholesalePricing=1 then VolumetricCharge end) WholesaleWaterVar,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Waste' and WholesalePricing=1 then FixedCharge end) WholesaleWasteFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Waste' and WholesalePricing=1 then VolumetricCharge end) WholesaleWasteVar,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Roads Drainage' and WholesalePricing=1 then FixedCharge end) WholesaleRoadsFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Roads Drainage' and WholesalePricing=1 then VolumetricCharge end) WholesaleRoadsVar,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Property Drainage' and WholesalePricing=1 then FixedCharge end) WholesalePropertyFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Property Drainage' and WholesalePricing=1 then VolumetricCharge end) WholesalePropertyVar

 from PremiseMeteredPricings
 where UserId = 'cdb370f7-b995-4d99-adc9-c00c7e837bb4'
group by PremiseId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a second `group by` statement with your `union`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM premises p
INNER JOIN
(
select PremiseId,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Water' and WholesalePricing=0 then FixedCharge end) RetailWaterFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Water' and WholesalePricing=0 then VolumetricCharge end) RetailWaterVar,
  ...
from PremisePricings 
where UserId = 'cdb370f7-b995-4d99-adc9-c00c7e837bb4'    <--Here
group by PremiseId                                       <--Here 
union
select PremiseId,
  sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Water' and WholesalePricing=0 then FixedCharge end) RetailWaterFixed,sum(case when PricingCategory = 'Water' and WholesalePricing=0 then VolumetricCharge end) RetailWaterVar,
  ...
from PremiseMeteredPricings
where UserId = 'cdb370f7-b995-4d99-adc9-c00c7e837bb4'    <--And again here
group by PremiseId                                       <--And again here
) x on x.PremiseId = p.PremiseId 
order by CoreSPID
```

Comment: Even this says PremiseID is invalid column name on premise ID. Something fundamentally wrong: select PremiseId,count(*)
from PremisePricings 

group by PremiseId

UNION 

 select PremiseId,count(*)
 from PremiseMeteredPricings

group by PremiseId

Comment: @John -- does your `PremiseMeteredPricings` table have a `PremiseId` column?

Comment: Had to be something obvious I guess, lack of coffee this morning, thanks